# How to use mule requester for SFTP - Dynamic file name and path

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying to use a mule requester component for SFTP. How do I give the file name as part of the request argument? This is my flow:

```
<flow name="Move_Doc_To_Temp_Location" doc:name="Move_Doc_To_Temp_Location">
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="Select_Document" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="30000" connector-ref="LoanApp_Database" doc:name="Select_Doc_To_be_moved"/>
    <set-variable variableName="OriginalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="OriginalPayload"/>
    <logger message="#[payload['DocID']] - #[payload['Location']]" level="INFO" category="Document to be moved" doc:name="Logger"/>
           <!--  <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file:///#[payload['Location']]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/> -->
    <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="sftp://user:Pwd@Hostname#[payload['Location']]" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>  
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\jvas\Desktop\testfiles" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>        
</flow>
```

The location value resolves to /opt/Documents/test.txt. When I specify the filename like this, it throws me an error:

> ERROR 2014-07-24 05:51:12,358
> [[loanapp_document_flow].Move_Doc_To_Temp_Location.stage1.02]
> org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
> ******************************************************************************** Message               : Failed to receive event over:
> DefaultInboundEndpoint{endpointUri=sftp://muledev:@nylicvmmuledev/opt/Documents/test.txt,
> connector=SftpConnector {   name=SFTP1   lifecycle=start   this=aa033b
> numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
> createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true   connected=true
> supportedProtocols=[sftp]   serviceOverrides= } ,
> name='endpoint.sftp.nylicvmmuledev.opt.Documents.test.txt',
> mep=ONE_WAY, properties={},
> transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT,
> timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started,
> responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8,
> disableTransportTransformer=false} (timeout=1000) Code
> : MULE_ERROR-92
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>
> 1. Error 'No such file' occurred when trying to CDW to '/opt/Documents/test.txt'. (java.io.IOException)
>    org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient:102 (null)
> 2. Failed to receive event over: DefaultInboundEndpoint{endpointUri=sftp://muledev:@nylicvmmuledev/opt/Documents/test.txt,
>    connector=SftpConnector {   name=SFTP1   lifecycle=start   this=aa033b
>    numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
>    createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true   connected=true
>    supportedProtocols=[sftp]   serviceOverrides= } ,
>    name='endpoint.sftp.nylicvmmuledev.opt.Documents.test.txt',
>    mep=ONE_WAY, properties={},
>    transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT,
>    timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started,
>    responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8,
>    disableTransportTransformer=false} (timeout=1000)
>    (org.mule.api.transport.ReceiveException)
>    org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageRequester:132
>    (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/ReceiveException.html)
>    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.io.IOException: Error 'No such file'
>    occurred when trying to CDW to '/opt/Documents/test.txt'.     at
>    org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(SftpClient.java:102)
>    at
>    org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnector.createSftpClient(SftpConnector.java:196)
>    at
>    org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpConnector.createSftpClient(SftpConnector.java:174)
>
>    - 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

Now I tried removing the file name from the location, and the SFTP was successful, but it has randomly chosen a file. The file has all permissions for SFTP and I am able to do the SFTP via command line successfully. I have referred to the documentation for the SFTP URL and this is what it provides for resolving the file name from the URL : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-4.1

Retrieve file.txt from the user's home directory on the host at
host.example.com using SFTP using username user.  This example
assumes that the implementation supports the indication of a path
relative to the home directory using a leading tilde.

```
    sftp://user@host.example.com/~/file.txt
```

Retrieve file.txt from the absolute path /dir/path on the host at
host.example.com using SFTP using username user.

```
    sftp://user@host.example.com/dir/path/file.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mule SFTP connector can not take the filename in the address. Instead you need to use a filename filter. However, unfortunately I think the requestor module ignores the filters configured on the endpoint as mentioned here: http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/mule_module_requester_add_support_for_filenamefilter

You could however use a script to read a file over sftp mid flow. Something like:

```
<scripting:transformer>
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text>
                    def endpointBuilder = muleContext.endpointFactory.getEndpointBuilder( 
                    "sftp://${sftp.username}@${sftp.host}:${sftp.port}/${sftp.path}?identityFile=${app.home}/${sftp.keyPath}&amp;passphrase=${sftp.passphrase}&amp;connector=sftp-csv") 
                    endpointBuilder.addMessageProcessor(new org.mule.routing.MessageFilter(new org.mule.transport.file.filters.FilenameWildcardFilter(sessionVars.expectedFilename))) 
                    def inboundEndpoint = endpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint() 
                    inboundEndpoint.request(30000L) 
                </scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
```

Comment: Just one question, what does the 30000L stand for? Is that a timeout setting?

Comment: Great :) accept the answer then? Because its requesting a file, it will wait up to 30000 milliseconds to retrieve it. You can change this to whatever you want.

Comment: Because its requesting a file, it will wait up to 30000 milliseconds to retrieve it. You can change this to whatever you want.

Comment: I just noticed that it doesn't handle exceptions like how the mule components do. For eg; If the file isn't there, it returns me a NullPayload. Is there a way to handle this? Do you know how I can get the actual SFTP error message? (For eg; if a directory is not accessible, etc)

Comment: what is the identity file and passphrase? what is it used for. I guess passphrase is the password. So what is identity file used for then? To verify the remote server? but how can you please point out to some resources for the same.