# Scheduling SFTP

Tags: mule, sftp

I have a requirement to call an sftp endpoint every morning at 6 am and process files. Is it possible to wrap a poll scope around an sftp inbound?

There is a polling frequency in SFTP connector but thats in milliseconds and I don't think we can control it to run at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could read the file in the middle of the flow using a simple script as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930875/how-to-use-mule-requester-for-sftp-dynamic-file-name-and-path) and than add a [quartz inbound endpoint](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/quartz-connector) to your flow where you can use a cron expression for scheduling.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The [poll](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/poll-reference) process is not suitable for your situation as you want your job to run at fixed time and not whenever a file arrives at `sftp`. [Quartz connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/quartz-connector)  can help you achieve that. you'd need to define [cron](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) expression for your `quartz inbound endpoint`. Following `cron` job will trigger everyday at 6am, you could customize it per your needs.

```
# sec(0-59) min(0-59) hour(0-23) day of month(1-31) month(1-12) day of week(0-6)(Sunday=0) 

cron=0 0 6  * * ?
```

I'd suggest to use [Mule Requester Module](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/) to request file from `sftp` - That's the mule recommended solution going forward. You could find an example of how to use it [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/blob/master/mulerequesterdemo/src/main/app/MuleRequesterDemo.xml)

Comment: Thanks I tried the requester and ftp only picks up one file no matter whether you give request-collection and count.. I will have multiple files.